# In Multicol environment using solution box, equation overruns box

Tags: multicolumn, framed

The code creates a 3 column math solution set with the step-by-step solutions framed in a box.

For problem #4, the equation over-runs the box.

[image]

I tried reducing the font from 12 pt to 11 pt.
`\documentclass[11pt]{exam}`

I also tried reducing the distance between columns:

`column-sep=1em`  and increasing  `\begin{solutionorbox}[3cm]` from 3cm to 5cm.

Didn't fix the over-run.

Is there a way to widen the solution box itself?

Thanks very much for your expertise!

mwe

```
\documentclass[11pt]{exam}
\printanswers
% un-comment to print solutions.
\renewcommand{\solutiontitle}{}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=0.5in,include head]{geometry}
\usepackage{soul}
\pagestyle{head}
\header{Algebra II: Problem Set D}
       {}
       {Due 04/25/23} 

\newcommand{\pagetop}{%
\noindent 
  
  \bigskip
  \vspace{0.5mm}
}

\settasks{after-item-skip=1em,
          after-skip=2cm,
          label-width=1.5em, %<---------
          item-indent=2em,   %<---------
          label=(\arabic*),
          column-sep=1em     %<----------
          }
\begin{document}
%definition for bigskip = 1 line to replace all \bigskip
\def\bigskip{\vskip\bigskipamount}

\textbf{Simplify.}
\begin{tasks}
[style=enumerate](3)
% Prob #1
\task 
$\sqrt{27}$
\vspace{3mm}
\begin{solutionorbox}[3cm]
$=\sqrt{9}\sqrt{3}$
\bigskip
\hl{$=\mathbf{3\sqrt{3}}$}
\end{solutionorbox}
\vspace{0.25cm}

% Prob #2
\task 
$3\sqrt{48}$
\vspace{3mm}
\begin{solutionorbox}[3cm]
$=3\sqrt{16}\sqrt{3}$
\bigskip
$(3)(4)\sqrt{3}$
\bigskip
\hl{$=\mathbf{12\sqrt{3}}$}
\end{solutionorbox}
\vspace{0.25cm}

% Prob #3
\task 
$5\sqrt{12}$
\vspace{3mm}
\begin{solutionorbox}[3cm]
$=5\sqrt{4}\sqrt{3}$
\bigskip
$=(5)(2)\sqrt{3}$
\bigskip
\hl{$=\mathbf{10\sqrt{3}}$}
\end{solutionorbox}
\vspace{0.25cm}

% Prob #4
\task 
$\sqrt{x^{10}}$ 
\vspace{3mm}
\begin{solutionorbox}[3cm]
$=\sqrt{x^2}\sqrt{x^2}\sqrt{x^2}\sqrt{x^2}\sqrt{x^2}$
\bigskip
$=(x^1)(x^1)(x^1)(x^1)(x^1)$
\bigskip
\hl{$=\mathbf{x^5=x^{10\div2}}$}
\end{solutionorbox}
\vspace{0.25cm}

% Prob #5
\task 
$\sqrt{a^{4}b^{12}}$ 
\vspace{3mm}
\begin{solutionorbox}[3cm]
$=(a^{4\div2})(b^{12\div2})$
\bigskip
\hl{$=\mathbf{b^6x^2}$}
\end{solutionorbox}
\vspace{0.25cm}

% Prob #6
\task 
$2a^2\sqrt{a^8}$ 
\vspace{3mm}
\begin{solutionorbox}[3cm]
$=(2a^2)(a^{8\div2})$
\bigskip
$=(2a^2)(a^4)$
\bigskip
\hl{$=\mathbf{2a^{2+4}=2a^6}$}
\end{solutionorbox}
\vspace{0.25cm}

% Prob #7
\task 
$3ab^2\sqrt{4a^6b^{14}}$ 
\vspace{3mm}
\begin{solutionorbox}[3cm]
$=(3ab^2)(2)(a^{6\div2)}(b^{14\div2})$
\bigskip
$=(3)(2)(a^1\cdot{a^3})(b^2\cdot b^7)$
\bigskip
\hl{$=\mathbf{6a^4b^9}$}
\end{solutionorbox}
\vspace{0.25cm}

% Prob #8
\task 
$5a\sqrt{18a^{20}b^{18}}$ 
\vspace{3mm}
\begin{solutionorbox}[3cm]
$=(5a)(\sqrt{9})(\sqrt{2}(a^{20\div2})(b^{18\div2})$
\bigskip
$=(3)(2)(a^1\cdot{a^3})(b^2\cdot b^7)$
\bigskip
\hl{$=\mathbf{6a^4b^9}$}
\end{solutionorbox}
\vspace{0.25cm}


\newpage

\end{tasks}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is to reduce the space taken up by each task by aligning the item number to the left side of the solution box, thus leaving room for the box to take up the full width of the column, thus avoiding overruns.

Here I am using the answer of a previous question [more space](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/683893/161015)  that included a change to the label width to accommodate two digits. For this purpose, the width is set to the width of the string `(99)\enspace` to make it independent of the font size, using

`\settowidth{\lwidth}{(99)\enspace}`.

The item indentation is set to `0pt` since the space between the label and  the `\task` contents is included in `\lwidth`.

The same length so defined is used to right shift the label and the `\task` contents.

The end result (`11pt` font size) allows to increase the column separation, for more clarity. In the same spirit, a bold font is used for task numbering.

[image: zz]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{exam}
\printanswers
% un-comment to print solutions.
\renewcommand{\solutiontitle}{}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=0.5in,include head]{geometry}
\usepackage{soul}
\pagestyle{head}
\header{Algebra II: Problem Set D}
{}
{Due 04/25/23} 

\newcommand{\pagetop}{%
    \noindent 
    
    \bigskip
    \vspace{0.5mm}
}

%%\settasks{after-item-skip=1em,
%%  after-skip=2cm,
%%  label-width=1.5em, %<---------
%%  item-indent=2em,   %<---------
%%  label=(\arabic*),
%%  column-sep=1em     %<----------
%%}

%**************************************************** only this code was added/ modified
\newlength{\lwidth}% added <<<<<
\settowidth{\lwidth}{(99)\enspace} % added

\settasks{after-item-skip=1em,
    after-skip=2cm,
    label-width=\lwidth, % changed <<<<<<<<<
    item-indent=0pt,   % changed <<<<<<<<<<
    label-format = \bfseries, % numbers in bold added <<<<<<<<<<
    label=(\arabic*), % 
    label-offset = -\lwidth,% added <<<<<
    item-format = \hspace{\lwidth},% added <<<<<
    column-sep=2em,    % changed <<<<<<<<<  
}
%****************************************************

\begin{document}
    %definition for bigskip = 1 line to replace all \bigskip
    \def\bigskip{\vskip\bigskipamount}
    
    \textbf{Simplify.}
    \begin{tasks}
        [style=enumerate](3)
        % Prob #1
        \task 
        $\sqrt{27}$
        \vspace{3mm}
        \begin{solutionorbox}[3cm]
            $=\sqrt{9}\sqrt{3}$
            \bigskip
            \hl{$=\mathbf{3\sqrt{3}}$}
        \end{solutionorbox}
        \vspace{0.25cm}
        
        % Prob #2
        \task 
        $3\sqrt{48}$
        \vspace{3mm}
        \begin{solutionorbox}[3cm]
            $=3\sqrt{16}\sqrt{3}$
            \bigskip
            $(3)(4)\sqrt{3}$
            \bigskip
            \hl{$=\mathbf{12\sqrt{3}}$}
        \end{solutionorbox}
        \vspace{0.25cm}
        
        % Prob #3
        \task 
        $5\sqrt{12}$
        \vspace{3mm}
        \begin{solutionorbox}[3cm]
            $=5\sqrt{4}\sqrt{3}$
            \bigskip
            $=(5)(2)\sqrt{3}$
            \bigskip
            \hl{$=\mathbf{10\sqrt{3}}$}
        \end{solutionorbox}
        \vspace{0.25cm}
        
        % Prob #4
        \task 
        $\sqrt{x^{10}}$ 
        \vspace{3mm}
        \begin{solutionorbox}[3cm]
            $=\sqrt{x^2}\sqrt{x^2}\sqrt{x^2}\sqrt{x^2}\sqrt{x^2}$
            \bigskip
            $=(x^1)(x^1)(x^1)(x^1)(x^1)$
            \bigskip
            \hl{$=\mathbf{x^5=x^{10\div2}}$}
        \end{solutionorbox}
        \vspace{0.25cm}
        
        % Prob #5
        \task 
        $\sqrt{a^{4}b^{12}}$ 
        \vspace{3mm}
        \begin{solutionorbox}[3cm]
            $=(a^{4\div2})(b^{12\div2})$
            \bigskip
            \hl{$=\mathbf{b^6x^2}$}
        \end{solutionorbox}
        \vspace{0.25cm}
        
        % Prob #6
        \task 
        $2a^2\sqrt{a^8}$ 
        \vspace{3mm}
        \begin{solutionorbox}[3cm]
            $=(2a^2)(a^{8\div2})$
            \bigskip
            $=(2a^2)(a^4)$
            \bigskip
            \hl{$=\mathbf{2a^{2+4}=2a^6}$}
        \end{solutionorbox}
        \vspace{0.25cm}
        
        % Prob #7
        \task 
        $3ab^2\sqrt{4a^6b^{14}}$ 
        \vspace{3mm}
        \begin{solutionorbox}[3cm]
            $=(3ab^2)(2)(a^{6\div2)}(b^{14\div2})$
            \bigskip
            $=(3)(2)(a^1\cdot{a^3})(b^2\cdot b^7)$
            \bigskip
            \hl{$=\mathbf{6a^4b^9}$}
        \end{solutionorbox}
        \vspace{0.25cm}
        
        % Prob #8
        \task 
        $5a\sqrt{18a^{20}b^{18}}$ 
        \vspace{3mm}
        \begin{solutionorbox}[3cm]
            $=(5a)(\sqrt{9})(\sqrt{2}(a^{20\div2})(b^{18\div2})$
            \bigskip
            $=(3)(2)(a^1\cdot{a^3})(b^2\cdot b^7)$
            \bigskip
            \hl{$=\mathbf{6a^4b^9}$}
        \end{solutionorbox}
        \vspace{0.25cm}         
        
        \newpage
        
    \end{tasks}
\end{document}
```

**Note**
The `solutionorbox` environment takes one optional argument:  the height of an empty box to be drawn  when solutions are not
being printed.

Comment: Another elegant layout solution! Thanks very much for attending to my request and need for symmetry in my math exercises.