# In \enumerate environment, create more space between double digit enumeration and the equation

Tags: spacing, enumitem

For problem numbers 1 - 9 the spacing between the enumeration # and the expression is spot on:

[image]

But for #10 and successive problems, the minimal distance between the enumeration # and the expression is so tight as to hinder readability. I don't want students to be confused on their exercises or tests.

[image]

Is there a fix for this problem?

Thanks so much for sharing your expertise.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{exam}
\printanswers
% un-comment to print solutions.
\renewcommand{\solutiontitle}{}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=0.5in,include head]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{soul}
\pagestyle{head}
\header{Algebra II: Problem Set D}
       {}
       {Due 04/07/23} 

\newcommand{\pagetop}{%
\noindent 
  
  \bigskip
  \vspace{0.5mm}
}

\settasks{after-item-skip=1em,
          after-skip=2cm,
          label-width=1.5em, %<---------
          item-indent=2em,   %<---------
          label=(\arabic*),
          column-sep=1em     %<----------
          }
\begin{document}
%definition for bigskip = 1 line to replace all \bigskip
\def\bigskip{\vskip\bigskipamount}

\textbf{Simplify.}
\begin{tasks}
[style=enumerate](3)
% Prob #1
\task 
$\sqrt{27}$
\vspace{3mm}
\begin{solutionorbox}[3cm]
$=\sqrt{9}\sqrt{3}$
\bigskip
\hl{$=\mathbf{3\sqrt{3}}$}
\end{solutionorbox}
\vspace{0.25cm}

% Prob #2
\task 
$3\sqrt{48}$
\vspace{3mm}
\begin{solutionorbox}[3cm]
$=3\sqrt{16}\sqrt{3}$
\bigskip
$(3)(4)\sqrt{3}$
\bigskip
\hl{$=\mathbf{12\sqrt{3}}$}
\end{solutionorbox}
\vspace{0.25cm}

% Prob #3
\task 
$5\sqrt{12}$
\vspace{3mm}
\begin{solutionorbox}[3cm]
$=5\sqrt{4}\sqrt{3}$
\bigskip
$=(5)(2)\sqrt{3}$
\bigskip
\hl{$=\mathbf{10\sqrt{3}}$}
\end{solutionorbox}
\vspace{0.25cm}

% Prob #4
\task 
$\sqrt{x^{10}}$ 
\vspace{3mm}
\begin{solutionorbox}[3cm]
$=\sqrt{x^2}\sqrt{x^2}\sqrt{x^2}\sqrt{x^2}\sqrt{x^2}$
\bigskip
$=(x^1)(x^1)(x^1)(x^1)(x^1)$
\bigskip
\hl{$=\mathbf{x^5=x^{10\div2}}$}
\end{solutionorbox}
\vspace{0.25cm}

% Prob #5
\task 
$\sqrt{a^{4}b^{12}}$ 
\vspace{3mm}
\begin{solutionorbox}[3cm]
$=(a^{4\div2})(b^{12\div2})$
\bigskip
\hl{$=\mathbf{b^6x^2}$}
\end{solutionorbox}
\vspace{0.25cm}

% Prob #6
\task 
$2a^2\sqrt{a^8}$ 
\vspace{3mm}
\begin{solutionorbox}[3cm]
$=(2a^2)(a^{8\div2})$
\bigskip
$=(2a^2)(a^4)$
\bigskip
\hl{$=\mathbf{2a^{2+4}=2a^6}$}
\end{solutionorbox}
\vspace{0.25cm}

% Prob #7
\task 
$3ab^2\sqrt{4a^6b^{14}}$ 
\vspace{3mm}
\begin{solutionorbox}[3cm]
$=(3ab^2)(2)(a^{6\div2)}(b^{14\div2})$
\bigskip
$=(3)(2)(a^1\cdot{a^3})(b^2\cdot b^7)$
\bigskip
\hl{$=\mathbf{6a^4b^9}$}
\end{solutionorbox}
\vspace{0.25cm}

% Prob #8
\task 
$5a\sqrt{18a^{20}b^{18}}$ 
\vspace{3mm}
\begin{solutionorbox}[3cm]
$=(5a)(\sqrt{9})(\sqrt{2}(a^{20\div2})(b^{18\div2})$
\bigskip
$=(3)(2)(a^1\cdot{a^3})(b^2\cdot b^7)$
\bigskip
\hl{$=\mathbf{6a^4b^9}$}
\end{solutionorbox}
\vspace{0.25cm}

% Prob #9
\task 
$\sqrt{a^{11}}$ 
\vspace{3mm}
\begin{solutionorbox}[3cm]
$=(\sqrt {a^{10}})(\sqrt{a^1})$
\bigskip
$=(a^{10\div2})(\sqrt{a^1})$
\bigskip
\hl{$=\mathbf{a^5\sqrt{a}}$}
\end{solutionorbox}
\bigskip

% Prob #10
\task 
$2a\sqrt{a^{13}b^8}$ 
\vspace{3mm}
\begin{solutionorbox}[3cm]
$=2a(\sqrt{a^{12}})(\sqrt{a^1})(\sqrt{b^8})$
\bigskip
$=2a(a^{12\div2})(b^{8\div2})(\sqrt{a})$
\bigskip
$=2a(a^6)(b^4)(\sqrt{a})$
\bigskip
\hl{$=\mathbf{2a^7b^4\sqrt{a}}$}
\end{solutionorbox}

% Prob #11
\task 
$\sqrt{49x^7y^{15}}$ 
\vspace{3mm}
\begin{solutionorbox}[3cm]
$=7(\sqrt{x^6})(\sqrt{x^1})(\sqrt{y^{14}})(\sqrt{y^1})$
\bigskip
$=7(x^{6\div2})(y^{14\div2})(\sqrt{x}\sqrt{y})$
\bigskip
\hl{$=\mathbf{=7x^3y^7\sqrt{xy}}$}
\end{solutionorbox}

% Prob #12
\task 
$\sqrt{24a^{17}b^{12}}$ 
\vspace{3mm}
\begin{solutionorbox}[3cm]
$=(\sqrt{4})(\sqrt{6})(\sqrt{a^{17}})(\sqrt{b^{12}})$
\bigskip
$=(2\sqrt{6})(\sqrt {a^{16}})(\sqrt {a^1})(\sqrt {b^{12}})$
\bigskip
$=2\sqrt{6}(a^{16\div2})(\sqrt{a})(b^{12\div2})$
\bigskip
\hl{$\mathbf{=2\sqrt{6}a^8b^6\sqrt{a}}$}
\end{solutionorbox}
\bigskip
 \task![]\textbf{Multiply and Simplify}% added <<<<<<<<<<  
% Prob #13
\task
$\sqrt{10}\boldsymbol{\cdot} \sqrt{6} $
\vspace{3mm}
\begin{solutionorbox}[3cm]
$=\sqrt{10\boldsymbol{\cdot}6}$
\bigskip
$=\sqrt{60}$
\bigskip
$=(\sqrt{4})(\sqrt{15})$
\bigskip
\hl{$\mathbf{=2\sqrt{15}}$}
\end{solutionorbox}
\bigskip

% Prob #14
\task
$2(\sqrt{5}) (4\sqrt{10}) $
\vspace{3mm}
\begin{solutionorbox}[3cm]
$=\sqrt{10\boldsymbol{\cdot}6}$
\bigskip
$=\sqrt{60}$
\bigskip
$=(\sqrt{4})(\sqrt{15})$
\bigskip
\hl{$\mathbf{=2\sqrt{15}}$}
\end{solutionorbox}
\bigskip

% Prob #15
\task
$2(\sqrt{5}) (4\sqrt{10}) $
\vspace{3mm}
\begin{solutionorbox}[3cm]
$=\sqrt{10\boldsymbol{\cdot}6}$
\bigskip
$=\sqrt{7}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\sqrt{7}$
\bigskip
$=\sqrt{49}$
\bigskip
\hl{$\mathbf{=7}$}
\end{solutionorbox}
\bigskip

\end{tasks}
\vspace{0.25cm}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `label-width` to the width of `(99)` to make it independent of the fontsize using `\settowidth`.

Use the same value for  `item-indent`.

(Note that some `solutionsorboxes` require a wider width. You can choose slightly smaller margins to allow for wider columns like `\usepackage[a4paper,margin=0.3in,include head]{geometry}`)

[image: y]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{exam}
\printanswers
% un-comment to print solutions.
\renewcommand{\solutiontitle}{}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=0.3in,include head]{geometry} %changed <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{soul}
\pagestyle{head}
\header{Algebra II: Problem Set D}
{}
{Due 04/07/23} 

\newcommand{\pagetop}{%
    \noindent 
    
    \bigskip
    \vspace{0.5mm}
}

\newlength{\lwidth}% added
\settowidth{\lwidth}{(99)} % added

\settasks{after-item-skip=1em,
    after-skip=2cm,
    label-width=\lwidth, %<--------- changed 
    item-indent= 2.2em,   %<--------- changed
    label=(\arabic*),
    column-sep=1em     %<----------
}
\begin{document}
    %definition for bigskip = 1 line to replace all \bigskip
    \def\bigskip{\vskip\bigskipamount}

\textbf{Simplify.}
\begin{tasks}
    [style=enumerate](3)
    % Prob #1
    \task 
    $\sqrt{27}$
    \vspace{3mm}
    \begin{solutionorbox}[3cm]
        $=\sqrt{9}\sqrt{3}$
        \bigskip
        \hl{$=\mathbf{3\sqrt{3}}$}
    \end{solutionorbox}
    \vspace{0.25cm}
    
    % Prob #2
    \task 
    $3\sqrt{48}$
    \vspace{3mm}
    \begin{solutionorbox}[3cm]
        $=3\sqrt{16}\sqrt{3}$
        \bigskip
        $(3)(4)\sqrt{3}$
        \bigskip
        \hl{$=\mathbf{12\sqrt{3}}$}
    \end{solutionorbox}
    \vspace{0.25cm}
    
    % Prob #3
    \task 
    $5\sqrt{12}$
    \vspace{3mm}
    \begin{solutionorbox}[3cm]
        $=5\sqrt{4}\sqrt{3}$
        \bigskip
        $=(5)(2)\sqrt{3}$
        \bigskip
        \hl{$=\mathbf{10\sqrt{3}}$}
    \end{solutionorbox}
    \vspace{0.25cm}
    
    % Prob #4
    \task 
    $\sqrt{x^{10}}$ 
    \vspace{3mm}
    \begin{solutionorbox}[3cm]
        $=\sqrt{x^2}\sqrt{x^2}\sqrt{x^2}\sqrt{x^2}\sqrt{x^2}$
        \bigskip
        $=(x^1)(x^1)(x^1)(x^1)(x^1)$
        \bigskip
        \hl{$=\mathbf{x^5=x^{10\div2}}$}
    \end{solutionorbox}
    \vspace{0.25cm}
    
    % Prob #5
    \task 
    $\sqrt{a^{4}b^{12}}$ 
    \vspace{3mm}
    \begin{solutionorbox}[3cm]
        $=(a^{4\div2})(b^{12\div2})$
        \bigskip
        \hl{$=\mathbf{b^6x^2}$}
    \end{solutionorbox}
    \vspace{0.25cm}
    
    % Prob #6
    \task 
    $2a^2\sqrt{a^8}$ 
    \vspace{3mm}
    \begin{solutionorbox}[3cm]
        $=(2a^2)(a^{8\div2})$
        \bigskip
        $=(2a^2)(a^4)$
        \bigskip
        \hl{$=\mathbf{2a^{2+4}=2a^6}$}
    \end{solutionorbox}
    \vspace{0.25cm}
    
    % Prob #7
    \task 
    $3ab^2\sqrt{4a^6b^{14}}$ 
    \vspace{3mm}
    \begin{solutionorbox}[3cm]
        $=(3ab^2)(2)(a^{6\div2)}(b^{14\div2})$
        \bigskip
        $=(3)(2)(a^1\cdot{a^3})(b^2\cdot b^7)$
        \bigskip
        \hl{$=\mathbf{6a^4b^9}$}
    \end{solutionorbox}
    \vspace{0.25cm}
    
    % Prob #8
    \task 
    $5a\sqrt{18a^{20}b^{18}}$ 
    \vspace{3mm}
    \begin{solutionorbox}[3cm]
        $=(5a)(\sqrt{9})(\sqrt{2}(a^{20\div2})(b^{18\div2})$
        \bigskip
        $=(3)(2)(a^1\cdot{a^3})(b^2\cdot b^7)$
        \bigskip
        \hl{$=\mathbf{6a^4b^9}$}
    \end{solutionorbox}
    \vspace{0.25cm}
    
    % Prob #9
    \task 
    $\sqrt{a^{11}}$ 
    \vspace{3mm}
    \begin{solutionorbox}[3cm]
        $=(\sqrt {a^{10}})(\sqrt{a^1})$
        \bigskip
        $=(a^{10\div2})(\sqrt{a^1})$
        \bigskip
        \hl{$=\mathbf{a^5\sqrt{a}}$}
    \end{solutionorbox}
    \bigskip
    
    % Prob #10
    \task 
    $2a\sqrt{a^{13}b^8}$ 
    \vspace{3mm}
    \begin{solutionorbox}[3cm]
        $=2a(\sqrt{a^{12}})(\sqrt{a^1})(\sqrt{b^8})$
        \bigskip
        $=2a(a^{12\div2})(b^{8\div2})(\sqrt{a})$
        \bigskip
        $=2a(a^6)(b^4)(\sqrt{a})$
        \bigskip
        \hl{$=\mathbf{2a^7b^4\sqrt{a}}$}
    \end{solutionorbox}
    
    % Prob #11
    \task 
    $\sqrt{49x^7y^{15}}$ 
    \vspace{3mm}
    \begin{solutionorbox}[3cm]
        $=7(\sqrt{x^6})(\sqrt{x^1})(\sqrt{y^{14}})(\sqrt{y^1})$
        \bigskip
        $=7(x^{6\div2})(y^{14\div2})(\sqrt{x}\sqrt{y})$
        \bigskip
        \hl{$=\mathbf{=7x^3y^7\sqrt{xy}}$}
    \end{solutionorbox}
    
    % Prob #12
    \task 
    $\sqrt{24a^{17}b^{12}}$ 
    \vspace{3mm}
    \begin{solutionorbox}[3cm]
        $=(\sqrt{4})(\sqrt{6})(\sqrt{a^{17}})(\sqrt{b^{12}})$
        \bigskip
        $=(2\sqrt{6})(\sqrt {a^{16}})(\sqrt {a^1})(\sqrt {b^{12}})$
        \bigskip
        $=2\sqrt{6}(a^{16\div2})(\sqrt{a})(b^{12\div2})$
        \bigskip
        \hl{$\mathbf{=2\sqrt{6}a^8b^6\sqrt{a}}$}
    \end{solutionorbox}
    \bigskip
    \task![]\textbf{Multiply and Simplify}% added <<<<<<<<<<  
    % Prob #13
    \task
    $\sqrt{10}\boldsymbol{\cdot} \sqrt{6} $
    \vspace{3mm}
    \begin{solutionorbox}[3cm]
        $=\sqrt{10\boldsymbol{\cdot}6}$
        \bigskip
        $=\sqrt{60}$
        \bigskip
        $=(\sqrt{4})(\sqrt{15})$
        \bigskip
        \hl{$\mathbf{=2\sqrt{15}}$}
    \end{solutionorbox}
    \bigskip
    
    % Prob #14
    \task
    $2(\sqrt{5}) (4\sqrt{10}) $
    \vspace{3mm}
    \begin{solutionorbox}[3cm]
        $=\sqrt{10\boldsymbol{\cdot}6}$
        \bigskip
        $=\sqrt{60}$
        \bigskip
        $=(\sqrt{4})(\sqrt{15})$
        \bigskip
        \hl{$\mathbf{=2\sqrt{15}}$}
    \end{solutionorbox}
    \bigskip
    
    % Prob #15
    \task
    $2(\sqrt{5}) (4\sqrt{10}) $
    \vspace{3mm}
    \begin{solutionorbox}[3cm]
        $=\sqrt{10\boldsymbol{\cdot}6}$
        \bigskip
        $=\sqrt{7}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\sqrt{7}$
        \bigskip
        $=\sqrt{49}$
        \bigskip
        \hl{$\mathbf{=7}$}
    \end{solutionorbox}
    \bigskip
    
\end{tasks}
\vspace{0.25cm}
\end{document}
```

**UPDATED** after follow up question: align the enumerate with the left side of the solution box.

[image: z]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{exam}
\printanswers
% un-comment to print solutions.
\renewcommand{\solutiontitle}{}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=0.5in,include head]{geometry} 
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{soul}
\pagestyle{head}
\header{Algebra II: Problem Set D}
{}
{Due 04/07/23} 

\newcommand{\pagetop}{%
    \noindent 
    
    \bigskip
    \vspace{0.5mm}
}

%**************************************************** only this code was added/ modified
\newlength{\lwidth}% added <<<<<
\settowidth{\lwidth}{(99)\enspace} % added

\settasks{after-item-skip=1em,
    after-skip=2cm,
    label-width=\lwidth, % changed <<<<<<<<<
    item-indent=0pt,   % changed <<<<<<<<<<
    label=(\bfseries \arabic*), % changed <<<<<<<<<<
    label-offset = -\lwidth,% added <<<<<
    item-format = \hspace{\lwidth},% added <<<<<
    column-sep=2em,    % changed <<<<<<<<<
}
%****************************************************

\begin{document}
    %definition for bigskip = 1 line to replace all \bigskip
    \def\bigskip{\vskip\bigskipamount}
    
    \textbf{Simplify.}
    \begin{tasks}
        [style=enumerate](3)
        % Prob #1
        \task 
        $\sqrt{27}$
        \vspace{3mm}
        \begin{solutionorbox}[3cm]
            $=\sqrt{9}\sqrt{3}$
            \bigskip
            \hl{$=\mathbf{3\sqrt{3}}$}
        \end{solutionorbox}
        \vspace{0.25cm}
        
        % Prob #2
        \task 
        $3\sqrt{48}$
        \vspace{3mm}
        \begin{solutionorbox}[3cm]
            $=3\sqrt{16}\sqrt{3}$
            \bigskip
            $(3)(4)\sqrt{3}$
            \bigskip
            \hl{$=\mathbf{12\sqrt{3}}$}
        \end{solutionorbox}
        \vspace{0.25cm}
        
        % Prob #3
        \task 
        $5\sqrt{12}$
        \vspace{3mm}
        \begin{solutionorbox}[3cm]
            $=5\sqrt{4}\sqrt{3}$
            \bigskip
            $=(5)(2)\sqrt{3}$
            \bigskip
            \hl{$=\mathbf{10\sqrt{3}}$}
        \end{solutionorbox}
        \vspace{0.25cm}
        
        % Prob #4
        \task 
        $\sqrt{x^{10}}$ 
        \vspace{3mm}
        \begin{solutionorbox}[3cm]
            $=\sqrt{x^2}\sqrt{x^2}\sqrt{x^2}\sqrt{x^2}\sqrt{x^2}$
            \bigskip
            $=(x^1)(x^1)(x^1)(x^1)(x^1)$
            \bigskip
            \hl{$=\mathbf{x^5=x^{10\div2}}$}
        \end{solutionorbox}
        \vspace{0.25cm}
        
        % Prob #5
        \task 
        $\sqrt{a^{4}b^{12}}$ 
        \vspace{3mm}
        \begin{solutionorbox}[3cm]
            $=(a^{4\div2})(b^{12\div2})$
            \bigskip
            \hl{$=\mathbf{b^6x^2}$}
        \end{solutionorbox}
        \vspace{0.25cm}
        
        % Prob #6
        \task 
        $2a^2\sqrt{a^8}$ 
        \vspace{3mm}
        \begin{solutionorbox}[3cm]
            $=(2a^2)(a^{8\div2})$
            \bigskip
            $=(2a^2)(a^4)$
            \bigskip
            \hl{$=\mathbf{2a^{2+4}=2a^6}$}
        \end{solutionorbox}
        \vspace{0.25cm}
        
        % Prob #7
        \task 
        $3ab^2\sqrt{4a^6b^{14}}$ 
        \vspace{3mm}
        \begin{solutionorbox}[3cm]
            $=(3ab^2)(2)(a^{6\div2)}(b^{14\div2})$
            \bigskip
            $=(3)(2)(a^1\cdot{a^3})(b^2\cdot b^7)$
            \bigskip
            \hl{$=\mathbf{6a^4b^9}$}
        \end{solutionorbox}
        \vspace{0.25cm}
        
        % Prob #8
        \task 
        $5a\sqrt{18a^{20}b^{18}}$ 
        \vspace{3mm}
        \begin{solutionorbox}[3cm]
            $=(5a)(\sqrt{9})(\sqrt{2}(a^{20\div2})(b^{18\div2})$
            \bigskip
            $=(3)(2)(a^1\cdot{a^3})(b^2\cdot b^7)$
            \bigskip
            \hl{$=\mathbf{6a^4b^9}$}
        \end{solutionorbox}
        \vspace{0.25cm}
        
        % Prob #9
        \task 
        $\sqrt{a^{11}}$ 
        \vspace{3mm}
        \begin{solutionorbox}[3cm]
            $=(\sqrt {a^{10}})(\sqrt{a^1})$
            \bigskip
            $=(a^{10\div2})(\sqrt{a^1})$
            \bigskip
            \hl{$=\mathbf{a^5\sqrt{a}}$}
        \end{solutionorbox}
        \bigskip
        
        % Prob #10
        \task 
        $2a\sqrt{a^{13}b^8}$ 
        \vspace{3mm}
        \begin{solutionorbox}[3cm]
            $=2a(\sqrt{a^{12}})(\sqrt{a^1})(\sqrt{b^8})$
            \bigskip
            $=2a(a^{12\div2})(b^{8\div2})(\sqrt{a})$
            \bigskip
            $=2a(a^6)(b^4)(\sqrt{a})$
            \bigskip
            \hl{$=\mathbf{2a^7b^4\sqrt{a}}$}
        \end{solutionorbox}
        
        % Prob #11
        \task 
        $\sqrt{49x^7y^{15}}$ 
        \vspace{3mm}
        \begin{solutionorbox}[3cm]
            $=7(\sqrt{x^6})(\sqrt{x^1})(\sqrt{y^{14}})(\sqrt{y^1})$
            \bigskip
            $=7(x^{6\div2})(y^{14\div2})(\sqrt{x}\sqrt{y})$
            \bigskip
            \hl{$=\mathbf{=7x^3y^7\sqrt{xy}}$}
        \end{solutionorbox}
        
        % Prob #12
        \task 
        $\sqrt{24a^{17}b^{12}}$ 
        \vspace{3mm}
        \begin{solutionorbox}[3cm]
            $=(\sqrt{4})(\sqrt{6})(\sqrt{a^{17}})(\sqrt{b^{12}})$
            \bigskip
            $=(2\sqrt{6})(\sqrt {a^{16}})(\sqrt {a^1})(\sqrt {b^{12}})$
            \bigskip
            $=2\sqrt{6}(a^{16\div2})(\sqrt{a})(b^{12\div2})$
            \bigskip
            \hl{$\mathbf{=2\sqrt{6}a^8b^6\sqrt{a}}$}
        \end{solutionorbox}
        \bigskip
        \task![]\textbf{Multiply and Simplify}% added <<<<<<<<<<  
        % Prob #13
        \task
        $\sqrt{10}\boldsymbol{\cdot} \sqrt{6} $
        \vspace{3mm}
        \begin{solutionorbox}[3cm]
            $=\sqrt{10\boldsymbol{\cdot}6}$
            \bigskip
            $=\sqrt{60}$
            \bigskip
            $=(\sqrt{4})(\sqrt{15})$
            \bigskip
            \hl{$\mathbf{=2\sqrt{15}}$}
        \end{solutionorbox}
        \bigskip
        
        % Prob #14
        \task
        $2(\sqrt{5}) (4\sqrt{10}) $
        \vspace{3mm}
        \begin{solutionorbox}[3cm]
            $=\sqrt{10\boldsymbol{\cdot}6}$
            \bigskip
            $=\sqrt{60}$
            \bigskip
            $=(\sqrt{4})(\sqrt{15})$
            \bigskip
            \hl{$\mathbf{=2\sqrt{15}}$}
        \end{solutionorbox}
        \bigskip
        
        % Prob #15
        \task
        $2(\sqrt{5}) (4\sqrt{10}) $
        \vspace{3mm}
        \begin{solutionorbox}[3cm]
            $=\sqrt{10\boldsymbol{\cdot}6}$
            \bigskip
            $=\sqrt{7}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\sqrt{7}$
            \bigskip
            $=\sqrt{49}$
            \bigskip
            \hl{$\mathbf{=7}$}
        \end{solutionorbox}
        \bigskip
        
    \end{tasks}
    \vspace{0.25cm}
\end{document}
```

You might want to use

```
\task![]\hspace{-\lwidth}\textbf{Simplify}
```

and

```
\task![]\hspace{-\lwidth}\textbf{Multiply and Simplify}
```

to left align the titles.

Comment: Another great, simple fix. The breadth of knowledge in this community is exceeded only by the generosity of members like you. Thanks! (your response marked "solved")

Comment: Can the enumeration indent be controlled independently of the margin? Specifically, I'd like to move the enumeration and the attached math expression slightly to the right so that it (i.e. the left parenthesis) aligns with the left vertical line of the solution box.

Comment: @Siuslaw Math Please see the updated answer.